# How to display nested cells in Element UI table?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am using [Element UI](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table). I have nested data that I need to display in table. The problem that I can't understand how to display nested data.

Here is my code:

```
 <el-table :data="tableData" stripe border>
  <el-table-column width="170" prop="id"></el-table-column>
  <el-table-column width="170">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
    <!-- -->
    </template>
  </el-table-column>

 </el-table>
```

data section:

```
  tableData: [
   {
   "id":1,
   "nested": [{"name": "mike"}, {"name": "piter"}]
   },
   {
   "id":2,
   "nested": [{"name": "maria"}, {"name": "anna"}]
   },      
  ]

  };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3nhb79qc/

I want to display it's like: [image]

Comment: Could you share a link to the documentation which led you to believe `nested` has been defined for Element UI table elements?

Comment: Here's how you can have expandable rows in Element UI tables: https://element.eleme.io/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/en-US/component/table#expandable-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is using [span-method in Element UI Table](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#rowspan-and-colspan)

First, flat your data structure by using computed method:

```
computed: {
  expandData() {
    return this.tableData.reduce((a, c) => {
      const arr = c.nested.map(item => ({
        id: c.id,
        name: item.name
      }))
      a = a.concat(arr)
      return a

    }, [])
  }
},
```

then your data will become:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "mike"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "piter"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "maria"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "anna"
    }
]
```

After that define `objectSpanMethod` and use it in `el-table`

```
  objectSpanMethod({ row, column, rowIndex, columnIndex }) {
    if (columnIndex === 0) {
      if (rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
        return {
          rowspan: 2,
          colspan: 1
        };
      } else {
        return {
          rowspan: 0,
          colspan: 0
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/1pq96n5c/3/)